# VS2015 Update 2 / IIS EXPRESS / WCF / Windows 10 / Localhost - Request never receives a response

Tags: wcf, http, iis, express, visual-studio-2015

I am running on Windows 10, using VS2015 Enterprise and IIS Express 10.  I have an existing set of WCF services that run using these pieces on a development laptop.  I have these same components install on a development workstation and they do not work.  All code is pulled from TFS 2015, so the code and the solution's IIS Express configuration files are the same on both machines.  I have also compared the IIS Express configuration under My Documents and they are the same on both machines.  The web.config is set to HTTP and not TCP/IP for teh WCF service binding.

When I launch the WCF service using Internet Explorer or WCF Test Client, the response is sent but no reply is ever received.  I have used Fiddler to confirm the request is sent, but no reply is forthcoming.  It takes more than an hour for the browser to time out.  I have used netsh and the entries that appear on both machine are the same, except on the workstation the ESTABLISHED status stays in place while the browser is waiting for a response.

I am at a total loss at where the issue is.  The only behavior that I have noticed on the workstation is that "Navigation Cancelled" flashes briefly before the "Waiting for localhost..." appears.

Any suggestion would be welcome

Spinet from One of the WCF project files

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{49AD9EC1-BCCD-439B-BF2D-3DD23FA515AE}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>PCXWcfPartyService</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PCXWcfPartyService</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <WcfConfigValidationEnabled>True</WcfConfigValidationEnabled>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Snipet from .vs IIS Express applicationhost.config:

```
    <site name="PCXWcfPartyService" id="13">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Development\PCXMain\PCXWcfServices\PCXWcfPartyService" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54024:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Snipet from web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="DefaultBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <httpTransport transferMode="Buffered"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="PCXCommonBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="PCXCommonTCPBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <tcpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                    <connectionPoolSettings leaseTimeout="00:05:00"/>
                </tcpTransport>
            </binding>
            <binding name="PCXCommonNPBinding">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <namedPipeTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="PCXApplicationServiceBinding" receiveTimeout="00:1:00" sendTimeout="00:1:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="10485760"/>
                </binaryMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="PCXApplicationServiceTCPBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00">
                <binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="10485760"/>
                </binaryMessageEncoding>
                <tcpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                    <connectionPoolSettings leaseTimeout="00:05:00"/>
                </tcpTransport>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="PCXWcfPartyService.PCXPartyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="PCXCommonBinding" contract="PCXServiceInterfaces.IPCXPartyService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="PCXWcfPartyService.PCXPartyServiceDMZ">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="PCXCommonBinding" contract="PCXServiceInterfaces.IPCXPartyServiceDMZ"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="PCXWcfPartyService.PCXPartyServiceAsync">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="PCXCommonBinding" contract="PCXServiceInterfaces.IPCXPartyServiceAsync"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="PCXWcfPartyService.PCXPartyServiceDMZAsync">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="PCXCommonBinding" contract="PCXServiceInterfaces.IPCXPartyServiceDMZAsync"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultClientBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: of course it's good you provided that much of text, but some config snippets, or more details would be good to be provided. Please, see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added a few configuration snipets.  I hope that helps.